# getRandomInt always returns 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

I am using the function from [developer.mozilla.com](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```js
console.log(getRandomInt(1));

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

I need it to only be 1 or 0.

If I call the above script in the chrome developer console, then I always get "undefined"

[image]

Comment: a value which is smaller than one is multiplied with one and then floored. the result is always zero.

Comment: it's very simple with `Math.floor(Math.random() * n)` ... however many results you want (n) is what you multiply by ... 0 and 1 are two results ... so multiply by 2

Comment: And why does chrome give undefined? Notice that I have used the value 3 in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this behavior is `Math.floor()`. From the documentation:

> The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

Source: [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

What you need to use to make it work as per your requirement is `Math.round()`. As the documentation states:

> The Math.round() function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

Source: [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Please find this example below:

```js
console.log(getRandomInt(1));

function getRandomInt(max) {
   const random = Math.random() * max;
   return Math.round(random);
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Addition:**

And as `@Kaiido` mentioned you have an active filter with the value `name`. If you remove that you will see the value.

Comment: Why does chrome return undefined though?

Comment: Can you try `console.log('hello');` if this behaves exactly the same way or prints `hello` as it should? I have tried the example code from the answer and it shows the value in Chrome's developer tool as expected.

Comment: @Black because you have an active filter ("name") in your console output. The log is `0`  **then** `undefined` which is the return value of `console.log`

Comment: I must have entered that filter some weeks ago. I was not aware that chrome keeps it during sessions. Thx!